# Java JDBC -insert record into database only if it does not exist

Tags: java, mysql, database, jdbc

I have a method to check whether or not a record exists within a database.
It should return false if the record is in the database, however if it does not already exist it should insert the record and return true.

The code in its current state appears to work fine however if the record it is not inserting a new row into the database when required to, and I cant seem to work out why this is.

```
public boolean createRecord(Myuser myuser) 
{
    Connection cnnct = null;
    PreparedStatement pStmnt = null;
    try
    {
        cnnct = getConnection();
        String preQueryStatement = "SELECT * FROM MYUSER WHERE MYUSER.USERID = ?";
        pStmnt = cnnct.prepareStatement(preQueryStatement);
        pStmnt.setString(1,myuser.getUserid());            

        ResultSet rs = pStmnt.executeQuery();
        if (!rs.next())
        {
            String insertStatement
            = "INSERT INTO MYUSER VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
            pStmnt = cnnct.prepareStatement(insertStatement);

            pStmnt.setString(1, myuser.getUserid());
            pStmnt.setString(2, myuser.getName());
            pStmnt.setString(3, myuser.getPassword());
            pStmnt.setString(4, myuser.getEmail());
            pStmnt.setString(5, myuser.getPhone());
            pStmnt.setString(6, myuser.getAddress());
            pStmnt.setString(7, myuser.getSecQn());
            pStmnt.setString(8, myuser.getSecAns());
            pStmnt.executeUpdate();

            System.out.println("new user inserted");
            return true;
        } 
        else
        {
            System.out.println("user already in data base");
            return false;
        }

    } 

    catch (SQLException ex) 
    {
        while (ex != null) 
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            ex = ex.getNextException();
        }
    } 

    catch (IOException ex) 
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    finally 
    {
        if (pStmnt != null) 
        {
            try 
            {

                pStmnt.close();
            } 
            catch (SQLException e)
            {

            }
        }

        if (cnnct!= null) 
        {

            try 
            {
                cnnct.close();

            } 
            catch (SQLException sqlEx) 
            {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you should try `ResultSet rs = pStmnt.executeQuery(); if (! rs.next()) { ... }` instead. Maybe you should try **reading the documentation** to see how JDBC actually works, e.g. [The Java™ Tutorials - JDBC Basics - Retrieving and Modifying Values from Result Sets](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/retrieving.html).

Comment: So you have little experience with java but you want to work on advanced topics such as database interaction or j2ee stuff? Sounds like you are overburdening yourself. Consider learning that basic stuff first.

Comment: its for uni i mainly have experience in C# and i have some knowledge of mysql.

Comment: Please show the code of `getConnection()`. Also, you are swallowing exceptions. At minimum you should log them (or use `ex.printStackTrace()`.

Comment: You're doing this completely wrongly. You should be using a single atomic `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE IGNORE` statement. Your way suffers from timing-window problems.

Answer (score 1):

ResultSet rs = pStmnt.executeQuery() will return resultset that will never be null untill there is no exception if you want to check if records are there  you can use rs.next() method verify if there is any records are there or not in resultset

```
 public boolean createRecord(Myuser myuser) 
    {
        Connection cnnct = null;
        PreparedStatement pStmnt = null;
        try
        {
            cnnct = getConnection();
            String preQueryStatement
            = "SELECT * FROM MYUSER WHERE MYUSER.USERID = ?;";
            pStmnt = cnnct.prepareStatement(preQueryStatement);
            pStmnt.setLong(1,youruserid);
            ResultSet rs = pStmnt.executeQuery();
            if (!rs.next())
            {
                String insertStatement
                = "INSERT INTO MYUSER VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
                PreparedStatement ps = cnnct.prepareStatement(insertStatement);

                ps.setString(1, myuser.getUserid());
                ps.setString(2, myuser.getName());
                ps.setString(3, myuser.getPassword());
                ps.setString(4, myuser.getEmail());
                ps.setString(5, myuser.getPhone());
                ps.setString(6, myuser.getAddress());
                ps.setString(7, myuser.getSecQn());
                ps.setString(8, myuser.getSecAns());

                System.out.println("new user inserted");
                return true;
            } 
            else
            {
                System.out.println("user already in data base");
                return false;
            }

        } 

        catch (SQLException ex) 
        {
            while (ex != null) 
            {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                ex = ex.getNextException();
            }
        } 

        catch (IOException ex) 
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        finally 
        {
            if (pStmnt != null) 
            {
                try 
                {

                    pStmnt.close();
                } 
                catch (SQLException e)
                {

                }
            }

            if (cnnct!= null) 
            {

                try 
                {
                    cnnct.close();

                } 
                catch (SQLException sqlEx) 
                {

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks for the reply it helped me wrap my head around this task at least and I looked into ResultSet out how that works. The code runs fine with no errors now and it correctly determines whether or not the record is in the database, however for some reason it doesn't insert the new record into the database, even after adding "ps.executeUpdate();"