# how to check duplicate values go to database

Tags: java, netbeans

this is my code insert into db so i want to check duplicate value how to find an show this message "All ready exist this item code or item name"

```
    try {
        String sql = "insert into itemreg(ItemID,ItemName) values(?,?)";
        pst = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        pst.setString(1, icode.getText());
        pst.setString(2, iname.getText());

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Item saved");
        pst.execute();
        tableupdate();
        clear();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42743817/java-jdbc-insert-record-into-database-only-if-it-does-not-exist

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java JDBC -insert record into database only if it does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42743817/java-jdbc-insert-record-into-database-only-if-it-does-not-exist)

Answer (score 0):

When `ItemID` is defined as primary key you will get an SQLException when you try to insert a row with the same id.